# how to upgrade to pandas 2.0 in anaconda?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I am using anaconda. currently I have pandas 1.3 installed. how do I upgrade pandas to 2.0? I checked below website and there is pandas 2.0.3 available in anaconda with following command

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas
```

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas

However, if I use this below command, it shows me only pandas 1.4 will be installed.

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas
```

Then I will just use below command to install pandas 2.0.3. it has been long time since I got environment issue shown as below. Not sure which is the better way to upgrade to pandas 2.0? Thanks

```
conda install pandas=2.0.3

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
```

Comment: Gedas, as I mentioned above, this command can only install pandas 1.4.4

Comment: are you trying to do this in `base`?

Comment: You probably have packages in your environment that require pandas `<2.0.0` and as a result the environment solving doesn't work. Try creating a new venv: `conda create <your_env_name>` then `conda activate <your_env_name>` and then finally `conda install pandas=2.0.3`

Comment: @NotAName why not `conda create <your_env_name> pandas=2.0.3` in a single command?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, I was not familiar with this syntax (I don't really use conda)

Comment: I think you have more than one environment in your anaconda. If you go to environments tab, you may see that base already has 2.0.3. The best way to do it is to activate your env and then install. @NotAName already shared the commands for you

Comment: Hi Joe, no, I did activate the environment. I think the issue is related to conflict between pandas 2 and existing packages.

Comment: @roudan, I have added an option for you to do this using Anaconda Navigator. Let me know if you want me to explain this using CLI (command line interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to solve for installing Pandas 2.0.3 or any version to your specific environment.

**Using Anaconda Navigator**

Step 1: Go to Environments tab on your Anaconda Navigator

[image]

Step 2: Search for pandas in the right top corner search button

Step 3: Right Click on pandas and select 2.0.3

[image]

Step 4: Click Apply. It will update your Anaconda version to the required version. This is a simple way than doing it using CLI

**Using Command Line Interface**

Step 1: Go to command line and give `conda env list`

It will give you the following:

```
(base) xxxxx ~ % conda env list                    
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/xxxxx/anaconda3
Stack_Overflow_Test      /Users/xxxxx/anaconda3/envs/Stack_Overflow_Test
UCBerkeley               /Users/xxxxx/anaconda3/envs/UCBerkeley
```

Note that the one with * is the active one.

Step 2: Activate your environment using `conda activate <your env>`

You will get this:

```
(base) xxxxx ~ % conda activate Stack_Overflow_Test
(Stack_Overflow_Test) xxxxx ~ %
```

Step 3: Now list the version of pandas using `conda list pandas`

```
(Stack_Overflow_Test) xxxxx ~ % conda list pandas                 
# packages in environment at /Users/xxxxx/anaconda3/envs/Stack_Overflow_Test:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pandas                    1.5.3           py310h46d7db6_0
```

Step 4: To upgrade conda, you can just give `conda upgrade pandas`. Since you want to upgrade to specific version, you can give `conda install pandas=2.0.3`

It will go through the process and upgrade it. Here's how it did for me.

```
(Stack_Overflow_Test) xxxxx ~ % conda install pandas=2.0.3 
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/xxxxx/anaconda3/envs/Stack_Overflow_Test

  added / updated specs:
    - pandas=2.0.3


The following packages will be UPDATED:

  pandas                              1.5.3-py310h46d7db6_0 --> 2.0.3-py310h46d7db6_0 


Proceed ([y]/n)? y    


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
(Stack_Overflow_Test) xxxxx ~ %
```

Now your pandas is upgraded to the new version. To check you can do step 5.

Step 5: Check again using `conda list pandas` It will give you:

```
(Stack_Overflow_Test) xxxxx ~ % conda list pandas
# packages in environment at /Users/xxxxx/anaconda3/envs/Stack_Overflow_Test:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pandas                    2.0.3           py310h46d7db6_0  
(Stack_Overflow_Test) xxxxx ~ %
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, I appreicate it. Yes I followed your screenshot, right click and all the package has only one option active which is Mark for removal. all other options like Mark for specific version installation is grayed out so I cannot select. do you know any reason? Thanks

Comment: Interesting. Let me try and simulate this and see if I can get this version. in the meanwhile, I created a new environment and upgraded pandas to 2.0.3

Comment: Unable to simulate the problem you have. Please use the `conda install pandas=2.0.3` option (CLI version) to upgrade. Let me know if it doesn't work